# geometric interpretation of inverse of the product of the length of two line segments

Tags: geometry, means

given a line segment  with length `a`. pick  a random point within that line segment, would generate two line segments with length `b` and `a-b` where `0<b<a`. what kind of geometric operation would generate the value of `a/(b*(a-b))` ? or is it even possible?

Comment: What is your work on the subject ?

Comment: By geometric operation, do you mean a geometric construction that has length, area, or volume etc. equal to $1/(b(a-b))$?

Comment: @CharlesHudgins yes.

Comment: @JeanMarie purely for fun and trying to understand more about primitive geometry and math. actually i have some decision tree induction method related to this. trying to make a mapping from a  ellipse boundary to splitting criteria

Comment: Clearly we can form $b(a-b)$ by building a rectangle with sides $b$ and $a-b$. The question then is just how to form $1/x$ given area $x$.

Comment: Take a look at https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1275768

Comment: @JeanMarie thanks for the link, i figured that i have missed a very important definition of 1, in my case, the 1 is `a`, not sure the solution would apply

Comment: It's not hard to construct a length that represents your number, but finding a nice/simple geometrical interpretation seems harder. If only the $b$ was in the numerator... there are some very simple and nice geometrical constructions for $\frac{ab}{b-a}$ (e.g. make a right-angled triangle with lengths $x$ and $y$ and inscribe a square which has a side $z$ then $1/x+1/y = 1/z$).

Comment: Thanks ! I’m interested in both constructing the length and simple interpretation if possible!

Comment: As the numerator and denominator of $c:=a/(b(a-b))$ are not [homogeneous](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homogeneous_polynomial) expressions of the same degree, constructing a segment of length $c$ from segments of length $a$ and $b$ requires a segment of length $1$. Otherwise, you could scale the resulting figure by, say, $2$, and the same construction would yield a segment of length $c':=2c$ from segments of length $a':=2a$ and $b':=2b$; but $c'\neq a'/(b'(a'-b'))$. ... Now, with segments $p$, $q$, $1$, it's not difficult to construct $pq$, then $1/(pq)$, and then $(p+q)/pq$. Can you see how?

Comment: @Blue Fundamental remark (I had overlooked this aspect). You should give it as an answer that I would be happy to upvote.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(Converting comment to answer, by request.)

As the numerator and denominator of $c:=\dfrac{a}{b(a−b)}$ are not [homogeneous](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homogeneous_polynomial) expressions of the same degree, constructing a segment of length $c$ from segments of length $a$ and $b$ requires an auxiliary segment of length $1$. (Otherwise, you could scale the resulting figure by, say, $2$, and the same construction would yield a segment of length $c':=2c$ from segments of length $a':=2a$ and $b':=2b$; but $c'\neq \dfrac{a'}{b'(a'−b')}$.)

---

Now, with segments of length $p$, $q$, $1$, it's not difficult to construct a segment of length $pq$, then one of length $1/(pq)$, and then one of length $(p+q)/pq$:

[image]

- First, arrange $\overline{OP}$, $\overline{OQ}$, $\overline{OR}$ (of lengths $p$, $q$, $1$, respectively) with the first two on opposite sides of $O$ and the last perpendicular to them. Construct $\bigcirc PQR$ (via well-known methods), and extend $\overline{OR}$ to meet this circle at $S$. Then, by the [Power of a Point Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_of_a_point#Theorems), $|OP||OQ|=|OR||OS|$; that is, $|OS|=pq$.

[image]

- Next, construct $\overline{OT}$ (of length $1$) perpendicular to $\overline{OS}$. Construct the perpendicular to $\overline{ST}$ at $T$, and let it meet the extension of $\overline{OS}$ at $U$. Since $\triangle SOT\sim \triangle TOU$, we have $|OU|/|OT| = |OT|/|OS|$; that is, $|OU| = 1/(pq)$.
- Finally, construct a perpendicular to $\overline{PQ}$ at $P$, and a parallel to $\overline{TU}$ at $Q$; let these lines meet at $V$. Since $\triangle UOT \sim \triangle VPQ$, we have $|PV|/|PQ|=|UO|/|OT|$, so that $|PV|=(p+q)/(pq)$.

This completes the construction. $\square$

Comment: sorry, do you mind complete the how part?

Comment: @pengyu: Done! :)