# How to mark the inverse of a line length using Geometry?

Tags: geometry

[image]

Using some Geometry construction, how can we show the length 1/c on this figure (so that we end up depicting the inverse length)? Bottom line, You can make any construction, but given length c of this right angle triangle, show/create/mark something which equals 1/c.

Assume length b = 1 unit.

Comment: You don't have a length $1$ in your drawing. Without that, $\frac1c$ is meaningless.

Comment: You can assume side b to be a unit length -- i have edited the question. Thanks

Comment: See, for instance, the second step of [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3350685/409).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Draw a circle of radius $b$ centered at the intersection of $b$ and $c$. This circle intersects $c$. From that intersection, draw a line parallel to $a$ down to $b$. This new triangle (part of $b$, part of $c$, and the new line) is similar to the large triangle, with hypotenuse length equal to $b$. So the leg along $b$ has length $\frac bc$.